# Why does MSDeploy on AzureVM Stops working? ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC. (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: azure, iis, msdeploy

I have a MSDeploy installed on an Azure VM. I could easily deploy from VS2019 to the VM in a click. That was working until now, nothing changes(albeit a windows update few days ago). 
All of a sudden VS started reporting this

```
Error       Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("vm.cloudapp.azure.com") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.)

Could not connect to the remote computer ("vm.cloudapp.azure.com") using the specified process ("Web Management Service") because the server did not respond. Make sure that the process ("Web Management Service") is started on the remote computer.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC.
The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

Started digging for logs and traces on the IIS server installed on the VM. The closest I could get is this trace which doesn't tell the source of the Internal server error (at least not in a language I understand).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='freb.xsl'?>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<failedRequest url="https://vm.cloudapp.azure.com:8172/msdeploy.axd?site=SIT"
               siteId="1"
               appPoolId="WMSvcAppPool"
               processId="6704"
               verb="HEAD"
               authenticationType="NOT_AVAILABLE"               activityId="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="500"
               triggerStatusCode="500"
               timeTaken="671"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
...
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>4</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:31.585Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">FailedRequestsTracingModule</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>5</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:31.585Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">FailedRequestsTracingModule</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>PRE_BEGIN_REQUEST_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>55</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:31.585Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="RemoteAddress">41.58.93.151</Data>
  <Data Name="RemotePort">57269</Data>
  <Data Name="LocalAddress">10.0.1.4</Data>
  <Data Name="LocalPort">8172</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_ENDPOINT_INFORMATION</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>50</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:31.585Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="Headers">Host: vm.cloudapp.azure.com:8172
MSDeploy.VersionMin: 7.1.600.0
MSDeploy.VersionMax: 9.0.2606.0
MSDeploy.RequestUICulture: en-US
MSDeploy.RequestCulture: en-US
Version: 9.0.0.0
</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_REQUEST_HEADERS</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>12</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x80</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:31.585Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="RequestURL">/msdeploy.axd?site=SIT</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>URL_CACHE_ACCESS_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>Cache</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{AC1D69F1-BF33-4CA0-9313-BCA13873E1DC}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>13</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x80</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:31.585Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="PhysicalPath"></Data>
  <Data Name="URLInfoFromCache">false</Data>
  <Data Name="URLInfoAddedToCache">true</Data>
  <Data Name="ErrorCode">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>URL_CACHE_ACCESS_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>Cache</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="ErrorCode">The operation completed successfully.
 (0x0)</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{AC1D69F1-BF33-4CA0-9313-BCA13873E1DC}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>30</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:31.585Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="PhysicalPath"></Data>
  <Data Name="AccessPerms">512</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_GET_URL_METADATA</Opcode>
  <freb:Description Data="AccessPerms">Script</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>43</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:31.585Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="OldHandlerName"></Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerName">MSDeploy</Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerModules">ManagedPipelineHandler</Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerScriptProcessor"></Data>
  <Data Name="NewHandlerType">Microsoft.Web.Deployment.DeploymentAgentHandler, Microsoft.Web.Deployment, Version=7.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>HANDLER_CHANGED</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>41</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.053Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="Name">WebManagement</Data>
  <Data Name="Type">Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.WebManagementHttpModule, Microsoft.Web.Management, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>VIRTUAL_MODULE_UNRESOLVED</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>41</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.053Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="Name">WindowsAuthentication</Data>
  <Data Name="Type">System.Web.Security.WindowsAuthenticationModule</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>VIRTUAL_MODULE_UNRESOLVED</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>41</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.053Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="Name">WebManagementBasicAuthentication</Data>
  <Data Name="Type">Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.WebManagementBasicAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.Web.Management, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>VIRTUAL_MODULE_UNRESOLVED</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>41</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.053Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="Name">WebManagementAuthorization</Data>
  <Data Name="Type">Microsoft.Web.Management.Server.WebManagementAuthorizationModule, Microsoft.Web.Management, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>VIRTUAL_MODULE_UNRESOLVED</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.053Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">IpRestrictionModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.053Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">IpRestrictionModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.053Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">FailedRequestsTracingModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.053Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">FailedRequestsTracingModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.053Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">RequestFilteringModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.053Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">RequestFilteringModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.053Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">AspNetInitializationExceptionModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="ASPNET" Guid="{AFF081FE-0247-4275-9C4E-021F3DC1DA35}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>0</Version>
  <Level>0</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0xf</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.069Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ConnID">0</Data>
  <Data Name="Context ID">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="Data1">HEAD</Data>
  <Data Name="Data2">/msdeploy.axd</Data>
  <Data Name="Data3">site=SIT</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>AspNetStart</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{06A01367-79D3-4594-8EB3-C721603C4679}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="ASPNET" Guid="{AFF081FE-0247-4275-9C4E-021F3DC1DA35}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>0</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>7</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x1</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.069Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ConnID">0</Data>
  <Data Name="Context ID">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="Data1">/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-4-132300519915843730</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>AspNetAppDomainEnter</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>Infrastructure</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{06A01367-79D3-4594-8EB3-C721603C4679}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>56</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.178Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="HeaderName">Cache-Control</Data>
  <Data Name="HeaderValue">private</Data>
  <Data Name="Replace">true</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>56</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.178Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="HeaderName">X-AspNet-Version</Data>
  <Data Name="HeaderValue">4.0.30319</Data>
  <Data Name="Replace">true</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>3</Level>
  <Opcode>16</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-03-30T14:26:32.225Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="6704" ThreadID="6712"/>
  <Computer>Tracker</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{80000004-0000-FE00-B63F-84710C7967BB}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">AspNetInitializationExceptionModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">500</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpReason">Internal Server Error</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">0</Data>
  <Data Name="ErrorCode">0</Data>
  <Data Name="ConfigExceptionInfo"></Data>
 </EventData>
...
</failedRequest>
```

And event viewer doesn't contain any information either. I could only see logs for the last successful deployment. Same goes for "C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\Temp\WMSvc"

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue you could try below steps:

1) ping the remote machine

2) verify that the msdepsvc or wmsvc services are started

[image]

3) that the firewall isn’t blocking ports 80 or 8172.

[image]

the most important thing you need to check is your entered details in publish profile is correct.

you could confirm that by clicking in the Validate Connection.

[image]

The ERROR_COULD_NOT_CONNECT_TO_REMOTESVC error message could indicate that you’ve typed the IIS site name value incorrectly.  Verify the site name on the target server in IIS Manager and try again.

You could refer this below link for more detail:

[Troubleshooting Web Deploy problems with Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-web-deploy-problems-with-visual-studio)

[Troubleshooting Common Problems with Web Deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/troubleshooting-common-problems-with-web-deploy)

Comment: I can confirm its none of this. The request reaches the server, the firewall doesn't block and I can confirm the two services are running, hence the log. If stop the services, the error becomes "unreachable". And the site name I am using is also valid

Comment: @user2113394 which update you installed? did you add the port 8172 in firewall incoming rule?https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/user/azure-stack-dev-start-howto-vm-dotnet?view=azs-2002